# How to combine multiple print statements without overriding the previous print statement

Tags: java, printing, overriding

I want to write a code in which prints multiple print statements on the same line without overriding the previous lines. For ex:

statement 1: Hello "7spaces"World

statement 2:         java

statement 3: Hello   java   World

I want to achieve statement 3 by combining statements 1 and 2

EDIT1: My question may be ambiguous but it is not...I'm not able to convey properly.....basically I want to insert java between hello and world using two print statements

Comment: shouldn't statement 3 by "Hello World java" ?

Comment: variables do the trick

Comment: there are 7 spaces between hello and world and I want to insert java between them

Comment: the question is confusing at best. Do you want to use **character arrays/arrays** in general ? Because "inserting" anything between strings when printing to console / file does not make sense.

Comment: If you actually want to do the print statement thing then why can't you have 
`System.out.print("Hello "); System.out.print("java "); System.out.print("World"):`

Comment: I don't want to use character arrays. say my first print statement prints "hello              world" . Then I want to move the prompt to the beginning of the line and then insert "      java" between "hello              world" statement. So the entire output should look like "hello java world"

Answer (score 0):

```
String spaces = "       ";
String one = "Hello       World";
String two = "java";
String three = one.replace(spaces," "+two+" ");

System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
System.out.println(three);
```

The question is pretty vague, so I think this is what you want.

I've replaced the "       " between "Hello" and "World" with " java "

Answer (score 0):

You could use formatted printing if that helps..

```
System.out.printf("Hello %s World", "Java");
```

or use regex like

```
String str1 = "Hello        World";
String str2 = "Java";
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("[ ]{7,7}", " "+str2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need 6 spaces.

```
System.out.print("Hello      World");
System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bjava");
```

It won't work in the Eclipse console, but it *will* work on a command prompt.

---

Now, since you can't move the cursor forward, only backward, you may need to keep the current line in a buffer in memory for more complex scenarios, and just reprint the entire line.

In this case, you'd use `\r` to return to the beginning of the line, then print *over* the existing text. If your new text is shorter, be sure to pad with spaces to clear the existing text.